# How to find a function based on substituted arguments

Tags: analysis

I'm reading a analysis book for fun and I got stuck on a problem.

The task is to find the function $f$ if
$$f(x-y,x+y) = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2xy}$$

Since I can see the solution $\frac{x^2 + y^2}{y^2 - x^2}$ from the book (it's given in the back), I can backwards engineer the solution:

$$ \frac{(x-y)^2 + (x+y)^2}{(x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2} = \frac{x^2 - 2xy + y^2 + x^2 + 2xy + y^2}{x^2+2xy+y^2-x^2+2xy-y^2} = \frac{2x^2+2y^2}{4xy} = \frac{2(x^2+y^2)}{2\cdot2xy} = \frac{x^2+y^2}{2xy} = f(x-y,x+y)$$

But I don't think this problem is meant to be solved by knowing the solution first. So my question is how would you solve this problem if you wouldn't know the answer? Is there something that's like a procedure you can follow or do you just have to be clever enough to think of the intermediate steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another form:

$u = x - y$

$v = x + y$

Solve the system with $x = \frac{u+v}{2}$ and $y=\frac{v-u}{2}$, replace in $f$ and obtain

$f(u,v)$

Comment: I think this answer is best generalized to other forms of this problem. Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Note $$xy = \frac{(x + y)^2 - (x - y)^2}{4}$$ and $$x^2 + y^2 = (x + y)^2 - 2xy$$ Together, they imply \begin{align}f(x - y, x + y) &= \dfrac{(x + y)^2 - \frac{(x + y)^2 - (x - y)^2}{2}}{\frac{(x + y)^2 - (x - y)^2}{2}} \\ &= \frac{2(x + y)^2 - (x + y)^2 + (x - y)^2}{(x + y)^2 - (x - y)^2}\\ &= \frac{(x + y)^2 + (x - y)^2}{(x + y)^2 - (x - y)^2}\end{align} Thus $$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2 + y^2}{y^2 - x^2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think this is another way of being clever.